# C: File I/O - Code example from book vs reality. Omitt the .txt?

Tags: c, file, fopen, fclose, strncpy

I am current studying chapter 13 from the book C Primer Plus (6th edition) by Prata, Listing 13.2 on page 574 implemented in codeblocks using gcc. The code is shown below. I have a text file called eddy.txt (but Win10 omitts showing the .txt ending, so it only shows eddy). The program uses this text file as an argument via argc/argv[], reads the string and saves a modified version into a new file, called eddy.red

Going through the book explanation, the new text file is supposed to be called "eddy.red"
However, the new text file on my machine is called "eddy.txt.red"

Does anyone of you have an explanation as of why there is a difference between my output and the book example? Is it machine/compiler dependent? It seems that the ".txt" of the original file eddy.txt has gotten into the string name, so when the output is produced, the new file will be called "eddy.txt"+".red" = "eddy.txt.red". That is a bit unfortunate because it would be awesome if the new file would be directly saved as a .txt file, which would be the case if I would simply choose a name for the new file, e.g. "Alex": fopen("Alex.txt","w") instead of fopen(name, "w").

Thank you,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define LEN 50
/*
From C Primer Plus. Listing 13.2
*/

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;
    int ch;
    char name[LEN];
    int count = 0;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((in=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't open the file \"%s\"\n",argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strncpy(name,argv[1],LEN-5);
    name[LEN-5] = '\0';
    strcat(name,".red");
    if((out=fopen(name,"w"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot create output file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // copy data
    while((ch=getc(in))!=EOF)
    {
        if(count++ % 3 == 0)
        {
            putc(ch, out);
        }
    }
    if(fclose(in)!=0 || fclose(out)!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in closing files\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it comes from your your ... (sorry, I had to run out and puke) ... operating system. More seriously, go to your Windows file explorer settings and unset the option "hide extensions for known file types". Then it will be easier to detect when an application (your text editor for example) changes the file extension without telling you.

Comment: I do respect your opinion about my operating system. So you say that the file string in my program is read as "eddy.txt" and not as "eddy" is solely related to the fact that I am using Windows? If I had as Linux system running, the file string would be read "eddy" as opposed to "eddy.txt"?

Comment: No offense was intended in my joke, sincerely. It's just that I regularly encounter this situation with people (students but not only) which are very surprised with the fact that the filename they chose was switched to something else and this is not visible because the file extension is hidden. So if your filename is really "eddy.txt", then your program should use this exact same name; the hidden extension *feature* is just related to the the way the file explorer displays the files; your C program uses the actual filename.

Comment: No offense taken :) I actually did figure out why I am getting a different output. I used a true text file (eddy.txt) whereas the book uses a file eddy. So if I remove the .txt on my file NOT having a text file anymore, I can produce the same output as in the book. I did miss this fine yet important difference in the book. Thank you.

Comment: What name did you supply on the command line?  Did you say `eddy` or `eddy.txt`?  It looks like you said `eddy.txt` and when that was copied into `name` and the `.red` extension was added, you get `eddy.txt.red`, as expected.  If you said just `eddy`, I would expect that you'd fail to open any file (unless you _do_ have a file `eddy` with no suffix).

Comment: Hi Jonathan - yes that is exactly where I made the mistake, and you are correct with all your assumptions. I now can completely reproduce the outcome in the book. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

If `strlen(argv[1])` is less than `LEN-5`, then appending
`".red"` will not cause any trouble: there is sufficient
storage for 4 characters and the final `'\0'`.
But if `argv[1]` is longer, then an overflow of `name`
could happen.
That's why `strncpy()` is used with `LEN-5` instead of
`strcpy()`.
But `strncpy()` does not guaranty that the resulting string
will be null-terminated if the maximal capacity is reached.
Then it is safe (even if not really correct) to place the `'\0'`
five characters before the end (`name[LEN-5] = '\0';`).
This way we are certain that in the worst case we can append
`".red"` (even if the filename is somewhat truncated).

In many cases, when the filename is shorter, all of this
has no effect because there already is a `'\0'` before
`LEN-5`.
So `"eddy.txt"` will become `"eddy.txt.red"`.